# Does determinism require Modal collapse?

Tags: modal-logic, determinism

The question is pretty much self-explanatory, I was just curious if there is any possible way to show that Modal collapse isn't caused by determinism.

Comment: I'm not voting to close, and I know you say that the question is self-explanatory, but I would suggest at least linking to a Wikipedia/SEP article/section on modal collapse. I feel like I've seen this contention, or a similar one, before, but either way, I think I can see what you're getting at but without spelling out issues like logical vs. nomological necessity, etc. a random outsider might not see the point of the contention.

Comment: The question is *not* self-explanatory, one-liners never are. "Determinism" can mean a single timeline or multiple timelines, as in [many worlds interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) of quantum mechanics. "Modal" is also highly ambiguous, see [SEP, Varieties of Modality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-varieties/). Even with a single deterministic timeline logical, metaphysical and even physical (with different initial states) possibilities remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determinism requires nothing. Determinism only assumes.

In a deterministic system everything is necessarily as it is. There are no alternative possibilities or uncertainties of any kind.

However, that doesn't mean that there are only necessarily true statements. In a deterministic system there are no statements at all, no entities capable of making any statements.